# Why is it true that $\left< u,v \right> = u^\top M v$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products

My linear algebra teacher stated the following proposition:

> Let $V$ be an inner product space over $\mathbb R$ and $\mathcal B = (e_1,...,e_n)$ be a basis for $V$, then, if we define the matrix $M \in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb R)$ such that $M_{ij} = \left< e_i, e_j \right>$, then, if $u$ and $v$ are two column vector os $v$:
> $$\left< u,v \right> = u^\top M v$$

I tried to prove this but I wasent able to do so. Why is this true? Is this also true for a vector space over the complex numbers? Because the properties of the innter product would change if the field was $\mathbb C$. Is this a property for real vector spaces or for every vector space over a subfield of the complex numbers?

Comment: $\left< u,v \right>=\left< \sum_i u_i e_i, \sum_j v_j e_j \right>=\sum_{i,j} u_iv_j\left< e_i, e_j \right>=u^TMv$.

Comment: But if the vector space is complex then only the first argument of the inner product is linear. Does that mean that this is only true for real vector spaces? @Jean-ClaudeArbaut

Comment: For complex vector spaces we have $\langle u,v \rangle = v^*Mu$. Note that this also works for real vector spaces, since $u^\textsf{T}Mv = v^{\textsf T}Mu = v^*Mu = \langle u,v \rangle$.

Comment: It's *conjugate linear* in the second, so you can still expand. You get a [sesquilinear form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sesquilinear_form).

Comment: It does not need to be conjugate linear in order to be an inner product @Jean-ClaudeArbaut

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Complex_vectors

Comment: @EduardoMagalhães An inner product over a complex vector space is always linear in one of its arguments and conjugate-linear in the other